# GitLab: prevent users from accepting their own merge request

Tags: gitlab, pull-request

I have a group of developers working in a GitLab repository. I want them all to be able to create merge requests, but I want to make sure that there's a paper-trail of code review for each change, which means that the merge request *must* be accepted by someone besides the author.

I can set up something that sort of emulates this by using a protected branch, but then only a subset of people can accept merge requests into that branch. This is unnecessarily restrictive; any code can be accepted as long as it's gone through code review.

Is it possible to create such a workflow in GitLab? Specifically, is it possible to set things up so that a user can't accept their own merge request?

Answer (score 3):

Update 2019-03: CE wonfix: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30181 EE seems possible via: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/3845

Currently there seems to be no way of doing that. Request on the feature tracker: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6530328-disallow-merge-of-own-merge-requests-disable-self

Comment: Link is broken, but I think the current status is that this feature will not be implemented in community edition (see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30181), and it is not yet available in the enterprise edition (see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/3845).

Comment: @naught101 thanks for the links. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/3845 seems implemented in EE to me no?  Was closed by this merged MR: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/merge_requests/9007

Comment: Ah, maybe I misread. Seemed like there was ongoing conversation.